# How do I print certain parts of an array inside an array in python 3

Tags: python

How do I print certain parts of an array inside an array. For example: How do I print [0] of the [1] position of the following array:

```
testarray = [[1, 2, 3], ["icecream", "person", "bird"], [4, 5, 6]]
```

the result should be "icecream".

Comment: `print(testarray[1][0])`

Answer (score 0):

To index a single array you need to state which one you want to `print`

```
A = ["test", "Jam", "boo"]
print(A[0])

test
```

if each array has multiple values you simply do the same as before inside each one

```
A = [["Toast", "sausage", "eggs"], ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"]
print(A[0][0])
Toast
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ev. Kounis answer, you want to use `print(testarray[1][0])`
to print out the first entry (0) in your second array (1), i.e. `icecream` in the list `["icecream", "person", "bird"]`.

Running `print(testarray[1][1])` would retrieve `person`, and `print(testarray[1][2]` would retrieve `bird`.

You can read more about arrays (with plenty of examples) here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/python-array/.